# configure postfix to put the incoming mail into folder instead of send it to another machine

Tags: postfix

We have an webmail service.
Now, the MX record is postfix server (configured as domain relay) that check the mail with amavis, spamassain and clamav, and after that the postfix server  (or the amavis?) send  the email to MailEnable server (this is another smtp server, on windows) that save the mail into folder. Now, each 10 seconds we have .net program that parse the emails into our format.
What we want is to remove the step of the MailEnable. To config the postfix (or the amavis?) to save the mail into folder (with the Envelope Header!!)

Thank you!! :)

Comment: What do you mean 'envelope header'?

Comment: In the mail enable i receive two files. one is the email and another is the real recepient of the email, not the "to" header.

Answer (score 0):

What does "configured as domain relay" mean?  Do you mean you have

```
relay_domains = mydomain.com
```

in main.cf?

If so, you will need to remove that setting for mail to be delivered locally.

Then, if you have only one, e.g. user1@mydomain.com, user2@mydomain.com, etc, you should add

```
mydestination = mydomain.com
```

or similar to main.cf.  A better way is

```
mydomain = mydomain.com
mydestination = $mydomain
```

and you should probably add $myhostname and mail.$mydomain.com too, e.g.

```
mydomain = mydomain.com
mydestination = $myhostname $mydomain mail.$mydomain
```

See the [docs on mydestination](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) for details.

After removing relay_domains, you may also want to double check your relaying settings.  See [SMTPD_ACCESS_README](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html) as a starting point.

If you have many domains and are using virtual domains, see [virtual_mailbox_domains](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_domains) and [VIRTUAL README](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) for details.

Comment: All you wrote is how to remove the relay domain. but what do i need to do after that? 
One,  if the server delivering locally then i dont have the envelope header. 
Two, where is the server saving the mails?